# number of chances in hangman game in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just developed the hangman game in javascript. I want to add the number of chances the player is left with after giving a wrong answer. Let's say I want to give him a maximum of 7 chances. I also want it to be displayed in the prompt.

```
var words = ["THE GRAND BUDAPEST HOTEL","MATRIX RELOADED","GLADIATOR","BEN HUR","SAVING PRIVATE RYAN"];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) 
{
    answerArray[i] = "_";
    if (word[i] === " ")
    {
        answerArray[i] = "  ";
    }
}
var remainingLetters = word.length;
while( remainingLetters > 0)
{
    alert(answerArray.join(" "));

    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter or click cancel to stop playing.");
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();

    if ( guess === null)
        {
            break;
        }

    else if(guess.length !== 1)
        {
            alert("Please enter a single letter.");
        }
    else  
        {
                for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) 
            {
                if (word[j] === guess)
                {
                    answerArray[j] = guess;
                    remainingLetters--;
                }


            }

        }
}

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The answer was " + word);
```

Comment: So...what's stopping you?  How can we help? (Do you have a specific question?)

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `tries` variable at the beginning, initialized with max chances.

Add a condition to your `while` loop, `tries` must be > 0

Add it to the prompt :

```
"Guess a letter or click cancel to stop playing." + tries + " remaining"
```

If user don't guess a letter (figure this out yourself), decrement `tries`

At the end, check if user has succeeded (for example check if `tries == 0`)

If not, print that : (from http://www.berkeleyinternet.com/perl/node30.html)

```
var hangString = "";
hangString += " ________     \n";
hangString += "|        |    \n";
hangString += "|        0    \n";
hangString += "|       /|\\  \n";
hangString += "|       / \\  \n";
hangString += "|             \n";
```